# Dynamically Created Textboxes not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating textboxes in the Page_Load event and giving them values, however whenever I load the details I am getting the same output.  I always seem to get the first output I got, even on subsequent searches.

Here's what my code with the irrelevant information missing:

```
Textbox txtName = New Textbox();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadData();
}

void LoadData()
{
    txtName.Text = DropDownList.SelectedValue;
    tableCell.Controls.Add(txtName);
}
```

If `DropDownList` has two values (e.g. "Item 1" and "Item 2") and has autopostback enabled, first time it will generate and show "Item 1" in the textbox (the default value for the DropDownList), but if this is changed and the autopostback fires, the textbox does not change.

I've tried getting around this by creating a new TextBox, overriding the "LoadPostData" function to prevent this from loading, which got around the issue there, but then I couldn't view the data afterwards.

Any idea how I could get around this?  I may be approaching this in the wrong way.

Edit: I've added another item to `DropDownList` that removes `TextBox`, so that it can be re-created again.  It seems to show the correct data when it is re-created after being removed, but if I'm attempting to just edit it, this isn't updating correctly.

Edit2: Here's the rest of the code for this page in case this helps at all.  The objects which I'm having issues with are SBUName and SBUComments, which are both TextBoxes.  The same issue is also happening for SBUClientDropdown but I believe the resolution will be similar:

```
DBHandler DBHandler = new DBHandler();
List<string> clients = new List<string>();
List<string> clientGroups = new List<string>();
List<string> sbus = new List<string>();

// Objects for SBU changes
string previousSBU = "";
string previousSBUClient = "";
TextBox SBUName = new TextBox() { ID = "SBUName" };
TextBox SBUComments = new TextBox() { ID = "SBUComments" };
DropDownList SBUClientDropdown = new DropDownList();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clients = DBHandler.GetClients();
    clientGroups = DBHandler.GetClientGroups();

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        foreach (string client in clients)
        {
            SBUClientList.Items.Add(GenerateItem(client));
            ClientList.Items.Add(GenerateItem(client));
        }

        foreach (string clientGroup in clientGroups)
            ClientGroupList.Items.Add(GenerateItem(clientGroup));
    }

    if ((SBUClientList.SelectedValue.ToString() != previousSBUClient) || (SBUList.SelectedValue.ToString() != previousSBU))
    {
        previousSBUClient = SBUClientList.SelectedValue.ToString();
        previousSBU = SBUList.SelectedValue.ToString();

        sbus = DBHandler.GetSBUs(SBUClientList.SelectedValue);
        SBUList.Items.Clear();
        foreach (string sbu in sbus)
            SBUList.Items.Add(GenerateItem(sbu));

        LoadSBU();
    }
}

void LoadSBU()
{
    if ((SBUClientList.SelectedValue.Trim().Length > 0) && (SBUList.SelectedValue.Trim().Length > 0))
    {
        Entity thisSBU = DBHandler.GetSBUInformation(SBUClientList.SelectedValue, SBUList.SelectedValue);

        SBUTable.Rows.Add(GenerateHeaderRow("Client Name", "SBU Name", "Comments"));

        SBUClientDropdown.Items.Clear();
        foreach (string client in clients)
            SBUClientDropdown.Items.Add(GenerateItem(client));
        SBUClientDropdown.SelectedValue = SBUClientList.SelectedValue;
        SBUClientDropdown.SelectedIndex = SBUClientList.SelectedIndex;
        TableCell SBUClientCell = new TableCell();
        SBUClientCell.Controls.Add(SBUClientDropdown);


        SBUName.Text = thisSBU.sSBUName;
        TableCell SBUNameCell = new TableCell();
        SBUNameCell.Controls.Add(SBUName);


        SBUComments.Text = thisSBU.sSBUComments;
        TableCell SBUCommentsCell = new TableCell();
        SBUCommentsCell.Controls.Add(SBUComments);

        SBUTable.Rows.Add(GenerateRow(SBUClientCell, SBUNameCell, SBUCommentsCell));

        Button SBUSaveButton = new Button();
        SBUSaveButton.Click += new EventHandler(this.SBUSaveChanges);
        SBUSaveButton.Text = "Save SBU Changes";
        TableCell SBUButtonCell = new TableCell();
        SBUButtonCell.Controls.Add(SBUSaveButton);
        SBUButtonCell.ColumnSpan = 3;
        TableRow SBUFooter = GenerateRow(SBUButtonCell);
        SBUFooter.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
        SBUTable.Rows.Add(SBUFooter);
    }
}

void ShowMessage(string message)
{
    OutputString.Text = "<div class=\"message\">" + message + "</div>";
}

ListItem GenerateItem(string input)
{
    ListItem output = new ListItem();
    output.Text = input;
    return output;
}

TableCell GenerateCell(string text)
{
    TableCell output = new TableCell();
    output.Text = text;
    return output;
}

TableRow GenerateRow(params TableCell[] cells)
{
    TableRow output = new TableRow();
    foreach (TableCell cell in cells)
        output.Cells.Add(cell);
    return output;
}

TableRow GenerateHeaderRow(params string[] columns)
{
    TableRow output = new TableRow();
    output.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;

    foreach (string column in columns)
    {
        TableCell thisCell = new TableCell();
        thisCell.Text = column;
        output.Cells.Add(thisCell);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: How is txtName getting rendered to the page?  You never add it to the page, it is only in memory and never rendered.

Comment: tableCell is a TableCell in a Table which is already on the page (this Table is rendering correctly, and this TextBox is adding to the TableCell here correctly, even if the data in it is not displaying correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

previousSBUClient and previousSBU will always be blank on each post back, so why do you compare against them on the Page_Load?  If you want their values saved between postbacks you need to save them in ViewState, I suggest code like:

```
public string PreviousSBU
{
    get { return Convert.ToString(ViewState["PreviousSBU"] ?? string.Empty); }
    set { ViewState["PreviousSBU"] = value; }
}
```

**Perhaps its because you add multiple header rows to the table, and only the contents between the first through the second get displayed?  Any header rows after added don't get displayed?**

On each postback you add a new header row.  But the TextBox's are created on each postback and not saved between, so you shouldn't be seeing anything at all if thats the case.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out about the ViewState, I hadn't realised that.  With regards to the multiple header rows, I've tried adding an `SBUTable.Rows.Clear();` but the same still seems to happen, unfortunately.  Annoyingly, I can't vote you up as I don't have the rep yet, otherwise I would have, sorry about that.

Comment: Glad to help on the ViewState.  To help clarify the problem, I'd suggest a new test page that doesn't access a database or have any special cases, just a button that when clicked adds a row and textboxes as you are doing, but with hard-coded values, and see if that doesn't help.

Comment: Or you can go at this totally different with a Grid, since grids are made to have numerous rows that are populated from a database.  Grids are essentially html tables that dynamically create rows as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try both of these and see how they go, thanks a lot for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

To render txtName to the page, you should have something like:

`this.Controls.Add(txtName);` somewhere on the page, preferably in the Page_Init, though for what you've listed, at least before the LoadData() call in Page_Load.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out - I am doing this but I forgot to add this to the code above, I'll update this

Answer (score 0):

Taking a guess at the missing code but are you databinding your dropdown list? If you are you may be doing it every time instead of just when the page is not a postback.  Like I say, guessing at what's not in your question but you might want consider something like this instead:

```
if (!Page.IsPostback)
{
  MyDropDownList.DataSource = blah;
  MyDropDownList.DataBind();
}

myTextBox.Text = MyDropDownList.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: If I run it in Debug with a breakpoint in the LoadData() it does appear to have the correct value there, it's just when it renders on the page that it's incorrect.  Not sure if that will help

Answer (score 0):

Create your controls in OnInit event, becouse viewstate serialization happens between oninit and onload. Also check if it is postback, to avoid overwriting values from viewstate.

Comment: I've tried this: `protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) { base.OnInit(e); txtName = new TextBox(); }` but the same thing is occurring.  The values seem to be correct if I use a breakpoint to see the values there, it just seems to be the render of the txtName object that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I remember strange things happening if you don't supply an ID to the textbox, are you doing this?

txtName.ID="txtName";`

Comment: I've just tried this and still no luck, unfortunately.  I tried setting the ID in the way that you've said and also like this: `TextBox txtName = new TextBox() { ID = "txtName" };` but neither seemed to help

Comment: Ok, I don't think I can help you further without seeing your actual code.

Comment: I'll add all of the code from this page to see if that helps at all, just a moment